# Каким образом выгружается id_user (внешний ключ) в mysql базу

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, foreign-key

У меня есть таблица №1 у нее уникальный ключ id_user и есть таблица№2, которая имеет внешний ключ к таблице №1 к ключу id_user.Когда пользователь вводит данные в форму на сайте, автоматически выгружаются введенные данные, в базу в таблицу№1. Но когда пользователь вводит данные в другую форму должна заполняться таблица№2 также имеющая id_user.Вот запрос к таблице№2:

```js
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('..........');                 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =='POST')
{$code = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['code']);
$quantity = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['quantity']);
 $sql ="INSERT INTO table2 (code,quantity)"."VALUES ('$code','$quantity')";
    if ($mysqli->query($sql) === true)
    {}}  ?>
```

Саму форму я не размещаю.
Каким образом произвести запрос, чтобы выгрузились данные code, quantity и id_user? Когда я выгружаю в другую таблицу без id_user колонки, все выгружается.
Как правильно все выгрузить, чтобы заполнилась таблица№2.
Каким образом все работает с внешними ключами? В mysql таблица№2 создана с внешним ключом, фото прилагаю.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял все эти "выгружается", то внешние ключи тут не при чём. К добавлению данных в БД они не имеют никакого отношения. Делается обычный запрос на вставку, в него передается code, quantity и id_user. Откуда брать id_user - вопрос к автору поста. База данных этого точно не знает. И неким магическим "автоматическим" способом не угадает.

Если user_id известен, то просто добавить его в запрос. Если надо сначала добавить пользователя в таблицу 1, а потом добавить запись в таблицу 2, то так и делать:

- вставить в таблицу 1
- получить сгенерированный ид через mysqli_insert_id
- вставить в таблицу 2

Comment: Я так понимаю, нужно id_user каждого покупателя из таблицы №1 отслеживать и вносить его в таблицу№2(заказы)  ? Не совсем понятно, как отследить какие заказы сделал конкретный покупатель, если он не зарегистрировался, а просто ввел свои данные и сделал заказ.

Comment: Какая разница, зарегистрировался пользователь или нет. Строку в БД все равно надо добавлять. И внешние ключи здесь не при чем.